# Add CSS to a single column in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, css

Is there any way of targeting a single column in a document library?

I am wanting to apply CSS to just the **Name (linked to document with edit menu)** column (through a Script Editor or via the Masterpage, I don't mind as it will be needed for all libraries that are created within this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your previous posts ([this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257365/add-sharepoint-menu-ellipsis-to-end-of-document-library-using-javascript) and [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257828/hide-edit-menu-ellipsis-in-sharepoint-2013-document-library)), you display the menu ellipsis (...) for the last column in the view and want to hide the menu ellipsis for the Name (linked to document with edit menu) column.

In this scenario, the menu ellipsis for the Name (linked to document with edit menu) column is the first one. You can use the JavaScript to hide the first menu ellipsis (...) in the view.

Demo:

[image]

Use the scripts below on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ready");
function ready(){
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-list-itemLink");
    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
        // there are two link cells
        // get first link for each row
        if (i%2 == 0){
            links[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joanna - I've attempted to embed this in my page and it doesn't seem to be taking affect. Any idea as to why this might be?

Comment: Change ".hidden()" to ".style.visibility = 'hidden'". Check the edited answer

Comment: Thanks!! Finally something has worked - you're a legend :)

Comment: is there any way to add this to the materpage so it is picked up on all document libraries in this site?

Comment: Yes, you can. Place the script under <asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server"> tag in the master page. And then publish the master page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it via JS Link for List View. This tutorial learn SharePoint Templates for [Views](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) and for [Forms](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms)(new/display/edit) very deeply and comprehensive. I strictly advise you to consider full reading of them.